# How to replace some values inside a specific tag in a index.html file using a cypress automation test

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Currently, I'm working with Cypress test automation. I have an `index.html` file inside `cypress/downloads/sample/index.html`. The `index.html` file has the below structure.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://test"></script>
<script src="https://test2"></script>

<!-- sample Config -->

  <script>
        const authConfig = {
            clientID: "sample value",
            signInRedirectURL: "sample value",
            serverOrigin: "sample value"
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will get copy the content inside the script tag which will be displayed in an application UI using a button click for the copy operation so the copied content will be as below

```
<script>
    const authConfig = {
        clientID: "abcd1234",
        signInRedirectURL: "https://localhost:8000",
        serverOrigin: "https://localhost:8000"
    };
</script>
```

Method written for copy and paste operation is as below:

```
static CopyConfigs() {

        cy.get(COPY_ICON).click();
        cy.wait(7000);
    }

static pasteoperation(Location){
            cy.task("getClipboard").then((value) => {
                cy.writeFile(Location + "/sample/index.html", value);
            });
    }
```

writeFile will replace the whole `index.html` file content

**Need help on**
I want to replace(paste) the content copied to the `index.html` file by replacing only the script tag(related to authConfig) content inside the `index.html` file without replacing the whole `index.html` file content. So that the values for clientID, signInRedirectURL, and `serverOrigin` inside the script tag of `index.html` file will have the new values. Is it possible to read the `index.html` file and capture the script tag and replace the `<script>` tag content using Cypress automation? Appreciate your support on how to achieve this.

Comment: I can see you do an edit. My previous solution was assuming you wanted to access the script tag values & manipulated them on the browser. You can use `Node` built-in methods `writeFile` & `appendFileSync` to change the file content

Comment: Thankyou @Manuel Abascal for your quick response on this. I have included more information for the original issue to be more clear and the edit is complete now.

Comment: I have also made an edit. I'll make another edit with a working solution later today for your new edit scenario if you can't figure it out

Comment: Thank You. I will check on the reference links you have provided. Also looking forward to your reply later today with a supportive working solution as I am new to cypress :)